# How to fix this error in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, android-intent

I have started learning Android Application development for 15 days. I am newbie.Please help me to solve following error.

```
Error:Variable DeclaratorID expected after this token
```

location: Intent syntax

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button _loginBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        _loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        _loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v);

              Intent in1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TweetList.class);
              startActivity(in1);

             }
        );
     }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmwKw.png)

Comment: You forgot to add open bracket for onClick method. Instead of ; use {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to open the `onClick` method with `{`.

It should be :

```
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent in1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TweetList.class);
              startActivity(in1);
         }
```

Comment: good catch ... 30s. before me ... lol

Comment: Eran answer is correct. I suggest to use the onClick tag in XML when it's possible. IMHO it's easier to start but sometimes you don't have the chance to put it in your UI XML.

Comment: @Eran Thanks You saved my day